# Do you lose all your images if you delete the variant in Cloudflare Images?

Tags: cdn, cloudflare

I noticed that a bunch of my images were no longer showing up on my website. When I inspected the url, I get:
`ERROR 9425: Image access denied: This account doesn't have variant with this name`

I think I had deleted a couple of my variants because I thought that was meant for creating newly resized images based upon the variant settings. I didn't realize it cause an issue with images created in the past.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I recreated a new variant with the same name as the old one. The old images still work. I'm not entirely sure what this means, but if someone could explain it to me, and how it's beneficial, that would be great!